# Finding the X,Y coordinates of UIButton inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

My UITableView has static cells content that are constructed from 6 sections each with 1 row that holds several components. as a result the vertical scroll view is needed.

**The task I'm trying to accomplish:** Open a popover above a button that is located in one of the lower sections, it is visible once the user scrolls, so the x,y are dynamic.

I've try to set the popover frame according to the UIButton frame & bounds but it doesn't appear in the right location.

**Edit:** playing around with hard coded numbers i found that the x,y = 100, 668 but I've looked through all the components and could not find these numbers anywhere

please advice

Answer (score 3):

I do this to find the location of a tableview cell in relation to the overall view like this:

```
CGRect cellRect = [cell.superview convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
```

I'd guess that to find the location of a button you would exchange cell.frame with the button.frame:

```
CGRect buttonRect = [cell.button.superview convertRect:cell.button.frame toView:self.view];
```

Hope this works!

Comment: This is incorrect. You want `CGRect buttonRect = [cell.button.superview convertRect:cell.button.frame toView:self.view];`.

Comment: Good catch! I was just guessing.  I'll update the post.

Comment: The popover appears with a button click so how do i extract the cell?